# How to display image from theme folder in .phtml file

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to display an image in my phtml file but I can't seem to load this. Below is my code

```
<!--- Location: /app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom-page.phtml -->
<div>
    <img src="{{view url='images/v3.jpg'}}"/>
</div>
```

Now the image I'm trying to load is located in

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/web/images/v3.jpg

But I can't seem to be able to load this image. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 2):

1. Images in **Vendor/theme/Vendor_Module/web/images/filename.png** or **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/filename.png**

```php
<img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/filename.png'); ?>"> //phtml

<img src="{{view url='Vendor_Module::images/image.png'}}"/> //cms block/ cms page
```

2. Images in **Vendor/theme/web/images/filename.png**

```php
<img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/filename.png'); ?>" /> //phtml

<img src="{{view url='images/image.png'}}"/> //cms block/ cms page
```